# Draw this scheme on TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles, plot

I am currently trying to draw this graph using Tikz :
[image]

The fact is that I am a bit lost with this process since it's my first time trying to do so. I am reading a documentation but this is only about listing examples so I am proceeding by mimicry...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
 
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
    
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[step = 1cm, gray, very thin](-6,-2)grid(6, 2);
\draw[very thick, ->](-6,0)--(6,0)node[above]{x};
\foreach \x in {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
\draw(\x, 1pt) -- (\x, -1pt) node[below]{$\x$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Obtaining this :

[image]
For the moment :

- I don't know how to use letters instead of numbers in order to graduate my line : how to do so ?
- Furthermore, I don't know how to plot the rank of each interval above every "cell" : (1,...,(i-1),I,(i+1),...,N).

Could anyone help me to proceed please ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.:SE!

Reproduction of your image:

[image]

is done by:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick](-6,0) -- (-3.84,0) -- ++ (1mm,2mm) -- ++ (2mm,-4mm) -- ++ (1mm,2mm)
                        -- ( 3.36,0) -- ++ (1mm,2mm) -- ++ (2mm,-4mm) -- ++ (1mm,2mm)
                        -- (6,0);
\foreach \x/\i in {-5/x_{{1}{2}}, -4/x_{\frac{3}{2}},-2/, -1/x_{i-\frac{3}{2}}, 
                    1/x_{i+\frac{3}{2}}, 2, 4/x_{N_x-\frac{1}{2}}, 5/x_{N_x+\frac{1}{2}}}
\draw(1.2*\x, 2mm) -- ++ (0,-4mm) node[below]{$\i$};
%
\foreach \x/\i [evaluate=\x as \xx using \x+1] in {-5/1, -2/i-1, -0.5/i, 1/i+1, 4/N_x}
\path (1.2*\x,0) -- node[above, font=\small] {$\i$} (1.2*\xx,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- In above MWE are used elementary commands for drawing of Ti*k*Z pictures-
- For the first line is used combination of absolute and relative coordinates. Latter are used zig-zag part of line.
- Vertical lines, which divide main line into segments, are drawn in the `\foraech` loops. To this lines are added labels below of them.
- Description for loops you can find in chapter *88 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement*, where see:

  - for the first see  paragraph *Multiple variables*(page 1003) for general principle of use multiple variables. IN your case are `\x` for positions of bars and `\i` for labels below bars. Values are collected in pairs `\x/\i`  in the list in curly braces. In your case first such pair is `-5/x_{{1}{2}},`, the second is `-4/x_{\frac{3}{2}},` etc
  - for the second loop *Options to customize the foreach-statement* om pages 1004-1005. Option `evaluate` is used for determination of segments with labels above. At this `\x` determine start of segment`, evaluated` \xx`end of segment, and variable`\i` contain labels of segment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But please : would you mind take a bit of time to explain some lines ? For instance : I don't understand how this line is written : `\foreach \x/\i in {-5/x_{{1}{2}}, -4/x_{\frac{3}{2}},-2/, -1/x_{i-\frac{3}{2}}, 
                    1/x_{i+\frac{3}{2}}, 2, 4/x_{N_x-\frac{1}{2}}, 5/x_{N_x+\frac{1}{2}}}`

Comment: @Wiss, see added note in answer.